# Use class with operator []

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

i am trying to implement a "Integer" class with expect that it will work like a build-in type `int`. But i am having a problem: i can't use this class in operator `[]` like `int` See my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Integer
{
    private:
        int Value;

    public:
        Integer(int x = 0)
        {
            Value = x;
        }

        void SetValue(int x)
        {
            Value = x;
        }

        int GetValue()
        {
            return Value;
        }

        Integer& operator [] (Integer X);
};

Integer& Integer::operator [] (Integer X)
{
    // Code
}

int main()
{
    Integer X[10];
    Integer I(5);
    int i = 5;

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        X[i].SetValue(i+1);

    cout << X[i].GetValue() << endl;    // It still work
    cout << X[I].GetValue() << endl;    // Doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

What is a way (exclude cast operator) to make operator `[]` understand my Integer type like it does with `int`?

Comment: Your overloaded operator isn't called in your example at all.

Answer (score 5):

You are thinking about this the wrong way around. You don't need to overload the [] operator on your own class, you actually need your class to be convertable to int, which can be done by overloading the cast operator.

```
class Integer
{
public:
  operator int () const { return Value; }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of confusion here. The declaration of an *array* of type `T` takes the form

```
T t[n];
```

where `n` is a compile time evaluable constant expression for the array size.

This **does not** invoke any `[]` operator defined within `T`, and neither does a subsequent access of an element via the expression `t[i]` for an integral type `i`.

If, in your case, you want `X[I]` to be compilable then you need to provide an operator that allows `I` to be treated as an array index (more formally the language requires a primitive *integral type*). A cast operator to `int` is the obvious choice, with

```
operator int() const
{
    return Value;
}
```

being the implementation.

Comment: @TheBeardedQuack. You and I have a differing opinion on the intended question. Stack Overflow works best when there are multiple answers to choose from.

Comment: Explaining what's wrong is still good and gives the OP opportunity to learn, but perhaps add the correct way too?

Comment: @TheBeardedQuack: On a second read I was missing the crux of the question.

Comment: Thanks @Bathsheba, but i am looking for an other way without cast operator.

Comment: @LongChampion: Why? That's not possible if you want to use a primitive array, so you wouldn't be able to write `Integer X[10];`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a type cast operator to your class. This allows your class to be converted to a compatible type. See here for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

This function should do the trick for your class.

```
operator int() const { return GetValue(); }
```

Comment: Thanks @TheBeardedQuack, it worked!. But i had known about this way (from my friend). So i am looking for other way without cast expresion to do it.

Comment: That's the only way you're going to be able to do it (without explicitly calling functions). The array access operator expects a type of `int` so you must either convert a compatible type or simply provide with an int. For example you could do `X[I.GetValue()]` but your question implies you want to use the type directly in the operator

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to overload the [] operator.
You just need to make sure that you can convert your Integer into an int with int int operator.

Something like this would work better.

```
operator int() const
{ return GetValue(); }
```

Then you should also be carefull with your prints.

`X[i].GetValue()` is wrong since `i = 10` in your exemple. This will result in an execution error.

`X[I].GetValue()` is wrong in your exemple because de conversion between your class and an int is not possible without `I.getValue()`. I am surprise this doesn't result in a compilation error but overloading the int operator will result this issue tho.

Comment: Firstly, i don't think `X[i].GetValue()` is wrong. I must distinguish the 'i' of the main function from the `for` loop `i` - it is available in this `for` loop only.
Secondly, `X[I].GetValue()` actully cause compilation error :(.
You can compile and run my code to check it.

Comment: Anyway, if you implement the int operator, it should compile without any problem.